# change properties of ui-widget-content and ui-slider-range-max

Tags: jquery-ui, slider

I have the following that works well:
https://jsfiddle.net/jdLy4g8z/

I have a variable "invert" and if set to true, I would like that the background-color of the class `.ui-widget-content` is lightblue, and the one for `.ui-slider-range-max` is white (and vice-versa)

it is possible to modify the property of the class using javascript? or can I set another class to the slider itself ?

Answer (score 0):

stupid me. That was quite straightforward since this is standard jquery:

`$('.ui-widget-content').css("background-color" , "white");`